# mapping of menu Name "Main Menu" with variable name: primary_nav

Tags: theming, navigation

I am new to Drupal and would like to  know the details of constant/global variable:  $primary_nav 
 Observed this variable is pulling list of links from a Menu with Title : "Main Menu" . 
 I try to see the mapping of these in UI and DB, but could not find. 
Can you please help me to find out the mapping of this menu Name (  "Main Menu" )  with variable name : primary_nav  and where is it defined.

Comment: Do you use bootstrap theme?

Answer (score 0):

`$primary_nav` is template variable in Garland's [**template.php**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes%21garland%21template.php/7.x) file. It's a variable specific to this Drupal core theme. The HTML markup is rendered by the [`theme_links()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_links/7.x).

The main argument to the theme function is page template variable `$main_menu`, which is defined in [**theme.inc**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/7.x). This variable is set by [`menu_main_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_main_menu/7.x), which will retrieve a menu id setting then use that to look up data in the `menu_links` table (noted by `menu_name` column).